# Neural Network isn't learning anything meaningful using Triplet Loss

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, face-recognition, conv-neural-network

I am working on a triplet loss based model for this Kaggle competition.

Short Description- In this competition, we have been challenged to build an algorithm to identify individual whales in images by analyzing a database of containing more than 25,000 images, gathered from research institutions and public contributors.

https://www.kaggle.com/c/humpback-whale-identification?rvi=1

I have decided to use a Siamese network architecture and train it to give me encodings which I can then use to calculate the distance between two pictures of whales. If this distance is below a particular threshold the two pictures belong to the same whale and if this distance is greater then, they aren't the same whale.

This is the Triplet loss function(learnt it from Andrew's deeplearning specialization) I used but i also normalized the encoding's to make the loss function more interpretable(easier to determine margin and split point) across different models(if that makes sense).(First, tried it without the normalization and when it didnt work i tried normalizing.) I also have tried changing alpha(margin) and varied it from 0.2 to 0.6.

```
from tensorflow.nn import l2_normalize as norm_l2

def triplet_loss(y_true, y_pred, alpha = 0.3):
    """
    Arguments:
    y_true -- true labels, required when you define a loss in Keras, you don't need it in this function.
    y_pred -- python list containing three objects:
            anchor -- the encodings for the anchor images, of shape (None, 128)
            positive -- the encodings for the positive images, of shape (None, 128)
            negative -- the encodings for the negative images, of shape (None, 128)
    
    Returns:
    loss -- real number, value of the loss
    """
    
    anchor, positive, negative = y_pred[0], y_pred[1], y_pred[2]
    anchor, positive, negative = norm_l2(anchor), norm_l2(positive), norm_l2(negative)

    # Step 1: Compute the (encoding) distance between the anchor and the positive
    pos_dist = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(anchor,positive)), axis = -1)
    # Step 2: Compute the (encoding) distance between the anchor and the negative
    neg_dist = tf.reduce_sum(tf.square(tf.subtract(anchor,negative)), axis = -1)
    # Step 3: subtract the two previous distances and add alpha.
    basic_loss = tf.add(tf.subtract(pos_dist, neg_dist), alpha)
    # Step 4: Take the maximum of basic_loss and 0.0. Sum over the training examples.
    loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.maximum(basic_loss, 0.0))
  
    return loss
```

This is an example of one of the model architectures i tried out. I have tried using pretrained Facenet, ResNet, DenseNet and Xception till now. I have tried Freezing different numbers of layers in each.

```
R = tf.keras.applications.ResNet50(include_top=False, weights = 'imagenet', input_shape=(224,224,3))

lr = 0.0001
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=lr)
R.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss = triplet_loss)

for layer in R.layers[0:30]:
    layer.trainable = False

em_Rmodel = Sequential([
                          R,
                          GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
                          #tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D(),
                          Dense(512, activation='relu'),
                          bn(),
                          Dense(256, activation = 'sigmoid'),
                          Dense(128, activation = 'sigmoid')
                          ])

def make_tripletModel(model):

    #I was manually changing the input shape to fit the default shape of pretrained networks
    A = Input(shape = (224, 224, 3), name='anchor')
    P = Input(shape = (224, 224, 3), name = 'anchorPositive')
    N = Input(shape = (224, 224, 3), name = 'anchorNegative')

    enc_A = model(A)
    enc_P = model(P)
    enc_N = model(N)

    tripletModel = Model(inputs=[A, P, N], outputs=[enc_A, enc_P, enc_N])
    return tripletModel

tripletModel = make_tripletModel(em_Rmodel)
```

I have been training using semi-hard triplets and have also been augmenting data properly to generate more training images.

This is the batch generator that i used for training. crop_batch is a function that crops images to show only the whale's tail, using which one can identify whales. It uses a DenseNet trained on more than 1000 images with whale tails and the bounding box surrounding it. Does the work sufficiently well.

```
def batch_generator_RN(batch_size = batch_size, ishape = (256, 256, 3), model_input_shape = (224, 224, 3)):
    triplet_generator = get_triplets()
    y_val = np.zeros((batch_size, 2, 1))
    anchors = np.zeros((batch_size, ishape[0], ishape[1], ishape[2]))
    positives = np.zeros((batch_size, ishape[0], ishape[1], ishape[2]))
    negatives = np.zeros((batch_size, ishape[0], ishape[1], ishape[2]))

    while True:        
        for i in range(batch_size):
            anchors[i], positives[i], negatives[i] = next(triplet_generator)
        
        anc = crop_batch(anchors, batch_size= batch_size, img_shape=model_input_shape)
        pos = crop_batch(positives, batch_size= batch_size, img_shape=model_input_shape)
        neg = crop_batch(negatives, batch_size= batch_size, img_shape=model_input_shape)

        x_data = {'anchor': anc,
                  'anchorPositive': pos,
                  'anchorNegative': neg
                  }

        yield (x_data, [y_val, y_val, y_val])
```

And finally, this, in general, is how i have been trying to train these models. I have tried reducing and increasing learning rate, batch_size = 16.

```
lr = 0.0001
optimizer = Adam(learning_rate=lr)
tripletModel.compile(optimizer = optimizer, loss = triplet_loss)


es = EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=20, min_delta=0.05, restore_best_weights=True)
#mc = ModelCheckpoint('Rmodel.h5', monitor='loss', save_best_only=True, save_weights_only=True)
rlr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='loss',min_delta=0.05,factor = 0.1,patience = 5, verbose = 1, min_lr = 0)

gen = batch_generator(batch_size)
tripletModel.fit(gen, steps_per_epoch=64, epochs = 40, callbacks=[es, rlr])
```

**So after training all these models, in some models the triplet loss does go down for a while but then plateaus and basically learns nothing meaningful(which basically means that just by looking at the distance between two embeddings i cant figure out if they are the same whale or not.). In other models, immediately after the first or the second epoch the weights converge and don't change at all and doesn't learning anything.**

I have tried a very wide range of learning rates and i am pretty sure that it isnt the problem.

Please tell me if i should add all the code files for you to understand the problem better. The reason i havent done it yet because i havent cleaned it but will gladly do so if required. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you say that it doesn't learn anything, is it that the loss reaches a plateau and thus it stops decreasing or it does decrease significantly but when you predict the embeddings of both same and different whales are are similar in value?

The `triples_loss()` fn and `batch_generator_RN()` fn are correct, the problem is not related to the data generation.

However, I suspect that your learning rate is too high while you freeze a lot of layers, i.e. numerous trainable parameters are frozen, which may lead to your network being unable to converge.

My suggestion is to unfreeze all the layers and decrease the learning rate to 0.00001 and start training again, regardless of the architecture that you use (Xception/ResNet etc.)

Comment: The loss reaches a plateau and then stops decreasing. Then when i use it predict the embeddings it hadn't learnt anything meaningful, which basically meant that just by looking at the distance between two embeddings i cant figure out if they are the same or not.

Comment: I have tried to unfreeze all the layers, tried initial lr = 1e-6(with ReduceLRonPlateau by a factor of 0.1), and also tried to not use imagenet weights at all and try to overfit the data. The architecture sure has the capacity to easily overfit the data, i think. But that didnt work too.

Comment: If you replace: em_Rmodel = Sequential([
                          R,
                          GlobalAveragePooling2D()
                          ])    does the error still persist?

Comment: Are you suggesting that i remove the dense layers on the model? I actually wanted to get feature vectors of shape (1,128). Removing the dense layer would change my feature vectors from 128 bytes to more than 2000. And i have also tried it but most of them features are just 0.0.

Comment: Sorry, keep only the dense(128), and remove the others.

Comment: I started to train it for 40 epochs, will take around 40mins. Also do you think i should remove the GlobalAveragePooling layers altogether and give it dense Layers and let it figure out which features are more important and how to reduce 100000 dimensions to 128?

Comment: em_Rmodel = Sequential([
                          R,
                          GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
                          Dense(128)
                          ])

Comment: The observation is to remove the sigmoid activation.

Comment: I tried it changing the model to what you suggested and changed the final activation from sigmoid to relu. Didnt work

Comment: Leave it linear... there is a reason why L2 normalization is applied

Comment: @No changes after leaving it linear?

Comment: Yes, no changes at all. Do you want to take a look at my entire notebook and i can walk you through it

Comment: Yes, please allow me to

Comment: uhmm i dont have enough reputation to msg you :(

Comment: put the link here and I will save it and then delete it

Comment: Run the first section to get data from kaggle. Then run all sections till Generators. You can skip running generators. Function and models section has all the functions required to train the net and seeing if coursera's method work was just a temp name i forgot to change, but it has all the cells used to train the network. The code ahead is just extra, un-needed code for now